# Adding Blender Datapaths together as strings and then executing the resulting string

Tags: python

is it possible to somehow execute this, so that I get the status of the show_name option?

```
import bpy

a = "show_name" 
b = "bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects['Cube']" + "." + a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
eval(b)
```

[eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) will take any valid Python expression string as argument.

To set a value, use

```
exec(c)
```

But be careful, [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) will execute ANY python code, so it is considered a very dangerous command, especially if the string is from user input.

I would advice rethinking how your code is setup, there is usually very little reason to access bpy in these fashion.

Comment: Is it possible to also set a value? For example:     a = "show_name" b = "bpy.data.objects['Cube']" + "." + a + " = True" c = eval(b) This doesn’t seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: eval() only works with 'expressions'. To set something is a statement. I edited my answer to reflect that.