# Invoking Operator fetched from C.window_manager.operators

Tags: python, scripting, operator

This follows my question ["Accessing Transform Operator History inclusive constraint_axis in Python script"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168702/accessing-transform-operator-history-inclusive-constraint-axis-in-python-script)

As you can see, I get an operator from the "history" stored in C.window_manager.operators inclusive properties:

```
lastoplist = []

if len(C.window_manager.operators[:]) > 0:
    lastop = C.window_manager.operators[:]
    lenop = len(C.window_manager.operators[:]) * -1
    ic = -1
    while ic > lenop:
        if "TRANSFORM" in str(lastop[ic]):
            lastopicstr = str(lastop[ic])
            lastopic = lastop[ic]
            lastoplist.append(lastopic)
            lastopattr = getattr(lastopic, "bl_idname")
            ip = C.window_manager.operator_properties_last(getattr(lastop[ic], "bl_idname"))

            ic = lenop
        else:
            ic = ic - 1

if len(lastoplist) == 0:
    print ("No Transformations!") else:
    print (lastopic)
    lastopicstr = str(lastopic).split('"')[1].split('_')[-1]
    print ("lastopicstr:", lastopicstr)

    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D': 

""" The result should work like this but with a operator matching the fetched one: """
                bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Here is how I tried to reinvoke the operator:

```
""" Here come all my weak attempts to invoke the fetched operator: """
                lastopic('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
                bpy.ops.transform.lastopicstr('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
                "bpy.ops.transform." + str(lastopicstr) + "('INVOKE_DEFAULT')"
                bpy.ops.transform.str(lastopicstr)('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
                bpy.ops.transform.lastopic('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
                bpy.ops.transform.lastop[ic]('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

How could I get this done?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20968/adding-blender-datapaths-together-as-strings-and-then-executing-the-resulting-st or this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36781/calling-a-method-from-a-string ?

Comment: `getattr(bpy.ops.transform, prop, None)`  if `prop = "foo" `  looks for `bpy.ops.transform.foo` and returns the operator callable or `None` if not defined.